# Spring Boot @RestClientTest how test with real server (not mock)

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

I need to create an integration test against a REST API. My service is using Resttemplate as HTTP client. The client code is generated from swagger file.

Running the test yields an error `java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET`

It seems that the test is running against a mock server. How to let the test run against the real server?

This is my current test setup (want to cut out a minimal test frame to get a fast test - booting the complete context is far too slow):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(value = { TpzConfig.class, TpzServiceRestImpl.class, ManufacturingPlantPhPmMapperImpl.class,
        ProductHierarchyMapperImpl.class, PlantMapperImpl.class })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "tpz" })
@RestClientTest
public class TpzServiceRestImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private TpzService to;

    @MockBean
    private ProductionPlantService ppService;

    @MockBean
    private ProductHierarchyService phService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<ProductManufacturer> pmByProductHierarchy = to.pmByProductHierarchy("001100909100100388");

    }

}
```

I need `@RestClientTest` to have a bean of RestTemplateBuilder.

Is there a way to configure `@RestClientTest` to use the real server (similar to `@DataJpaTest` where i can configure not to use h2)?

Answer (score 3):

`@RestTemplateTest` give you pre-configured `RestTemplateBuilder` and `MockRestServiceServer`.

1.You could `@Autowired` `MockRestServiceServer` and mock expected HTTP calls.

---

2.Remove the auto configuration :

```
@RestClientTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = MockRestServiceServerAutoConfiguration.class)
```

But that make the test kind of slow.. There is maybe a way to optimize it.

---

3.In another hand, you could remove `@RestClientTest` and in a test configuration file, create a bean of `RestTemplateBuilder`. Something like this :

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder getRestTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }
}
```

After this, add this configuration file in your imports :

```
@Import(value = { TpzConfig.class, TpzServiceRestImpl.class, 
ManufacturingPlantPhPmMapperImpl.class, ProductHierarchyMapperImpl.class, 
PlantMapperImpl.class, TestConfig.class })
```

And you should be good for your test.

Comment: thx. i'll try it. "I don't understand why you want to go on a real server in an integration test": because it is an INTEGRATION TEST - these don't have to run on a developer machine. integration tests also run in a different build phase and normally on an CI server providing the necessary environment.

Comment: We just have different definition/naming then ;) My stack is : unit test, integration test (start server locally but mock external services) and e2e test (run on environment with real external services and selenium do the calls).

Comment: In my case I wanted to run Spring rest test with another mock server, not Spring's own